# How to combine two excel sheets using python

Tags: python, excel

The merging of the two excel sheets is complicated.
Excel sheet1 contains

[image: Sheet1]

and sheet2 contains

[image: Sheet2]

The merged sheet should look like this
[image: Merged sheet]

The code written for that is

```
df1['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'] + ' ' + df1['time'])
df2['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'] + ' ' + df2['time'])
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Date', how='left')
merged_df = merged_df[merged_df['Datetime_y'] > merged_df['Datetime_x']]
```

The column names of sheet1 are Date,Code,time and sheet2 are Date,time,temp,dew.
But somehow it is not working.

Comment: Check the [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) function

Comment: What’s your error ? You can’t merge left because your date column has nothing unique to match on. You can try multiple columns